# I was trying to install the dependencies but getting the following error. How to resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, peer-dependencies

npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/labs @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\SENSA\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-07T05_56_29_194Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SENSA\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-07T05_56_29_194Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your version of npm is not suitable. You can try the following steps:

1. Use `--legacy-peer-deps` to install dependencies, run `npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/labs @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react --legacy-peer-deps`.
2. If the error is still reported, delete all node_modules and run this command again.
3. If the error is still reported, use `npm --version` to check your npm version, and then update to the latest npm version to solve this problem.